# Easier way to define properties in classic ASP?

Tags: oop, class, asp-classic

For every property in my class in ASP code I have to use this:

```
Public Property Get ItemsOnPage()
    ItemsOnPage = m_ItemsOnPage
end Property

Public Property Let ItemsOnPage(inp)
    m_ItemsOnPage = inp
End Property
```

This example is for the ItemsOnPage property. Is there any other way that I could use a subroutine somehow? I tried using:

```
sub subClassProperty(varProperty)
execute("Public Property Get " & varProperty & "()")
execute(varProperty & " = m_" & varProperty)
execute("end Property")

execute("Public Property Let " & varProperty & "(inp)")
execute("m_" & varProperty & " = inp")
execute("End Property") 
end sub
```

but this sub I can not call from Class :-((

Comment: Sounds like you're after `Dictionary` object that can store key/value pairs?

Comment: No I'd like to be able to write class easier not using 6 lines to define one property.

Comment: I fear such thing is not really possible in VBScript. You can however write classic ASP with JScript as well, if you're more comfortable with C-like syntax. You can have the class written with JScript and use it from VBScript code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could use a public statement, which is a bit simpler syntax.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd95z8%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

This illustrates a simple example

https://web.archive.org/web/20210506183450/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092399-1.2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is not a dynamic language in that sense. You can not modify the class at runtime.

I would suggest that instead of using properties, you use some common methods like SetProperty("propertyName", value) and GetProperty("propertyName) in the script that uses this class.

The internal mapping between the "propertyName" and value is up to you. If it's relatively small number of properties, you can use just a 2 dimensional array, or 2 arrays.

Comment: GetProperty? Could you be so kind to write my upper example using this? I can not find any documentation on SetProperty...